# Enabling Migrations issue

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

So I am trying to enable migrations in my project, however I am getting the below error:

> The term 'Enable-Migrations' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
>    name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

I did some research and the solution mostly proposed was to reinstall Entity Framework with:`Install-Package EntityFramework -IncludePrerelease`.  However, this line command is giving me this error:

> Install-Package : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'IncludePrerelease'.

And I can't really find any solution to this on the net.  Any idea of how I can solve this?

Comment: Have you tried restarting Visual Studio? Also, what version of Entity Framework are you using?

Comment: Yes I did restating Visual Studio.  And the Entity Framework version is: 6.0.  I also tried with the version 4.1 But in vain.

Comment: So is EF installed in your project now?

Comment: Yes. The 6.0 version.  But I am getting the same error.

Comment: You can try importing the EF Powershell module again, something like this: `Import-Module .\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.1\tools\EntityFramework.psm1`

Comment: nope, does not work.

Comment: "does not work" doesn't tell me anything. That command didn't work? The command worked but you still can't run "Enable-Migrations"?

Comment: Yes I did import EF Powershell but I still can't run Enable-Migrations

Answer (score 0):

Found this answer to a similar question, tried it and it worked!
This issue is occurring because we don't have Entity Framework installed. Please install Entity Framework using the below command.

Install-Package `EntityFramework -IncludePrerelease`
Once installed, choose the project in the package manger console default project drop down.

Make sure at least one class in your project inherits from data context, otherwise use the below class (personally i chose to put this code in a controller):

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext()
    {
    }
}
```

If we don't do this we will get another error:

No context type was found in the assembly

After completing these things you can run